# Comments that appear in my notifications (bell), sometimes do not appear in my videos / disappear!

Tags: youtube, comments

When viewing comments using the notification bell, I can see the comment - but when I come to click on it to reply (the new feature that let's you reply within the notification box) it just comes up with an empty box. I also then try to view it on the YouTube video itself, it's not there. I check it on the creater studio comment section, it's not there (and it's definitely not under Spam / Held for review before I get suggested that!)

I also know for a fact it's not the users fault, because a. I can still access their channel (so not a deleted channel case), b. it's not a deleted comment situation by the poster (as I've checked with some people and they've said they never deleted their comment)  
Any help would be appreciated! I've tried everything, and it's getting incredibly frustrating now...happening for a few months now. I've attached a image to show the issue.[image]